# Bicep to set Function App general settings

Tags: azure-functions, azure-bicep

I have a function app with the following setting:

> Basic Authentication : Off

How do I set this via bicep?

Comment: could you please shared your existing bicep file ? Also could you add more information => which version of function app ?  is it windows/ linux ? consumption / isolated app service plan ? dotnet-isolated ? Any information that could help.  I've just created a function app but can't find the basic auth setting in the portal for example

Comment: The basic auth setting is in; Configuration -> General settings in the Azure Function App service.

Comment: @GordonBy via bicep?

Comment: I've explained how to get the bicep. I'm not writing it for you 
At some point in the future Azure Portal exports will export in bicep, but we're stuck with json right now.
VSCode Bicep extension makes light work of converting the json to bicep, so there's really no issue.

Comment: As per bicep compiler and fundamentals you could append slot name to function app with -. What ch means it should be 'functionappname-slotname/SCM,'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top tip here is to go to your Resource Group in Azure and select `Export template`. Take the JSON output and put it to one side.
Make whatever change you need to the service in the Azure Portal, then `Export template` again. Now in your text-diff-checker of choice, see what parts of the template are different.

In your case you'll find that two new basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies resources have been created.

1. prevent ftp basic credentials
2. prevent scm basic credentials

Here's what I got in my export. To turn into bicep, use the **Paste as Bicep capability** in VSCODE.

```json
{
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
        "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_app_queueCode_5mkicgnmao6w2_name'), '/ftp')]",
        "location": "East US",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_app_queueCode_5mkicgnmao6w2_name'))]"
        ],
        "tags": {
            "azd-service-name": "app"
        },
        "properties": {
            "allow": false
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
        "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_app_queueCode_5mkicgnmao6w2_name'), '/scm')]",
        "location": "East US",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_app_queueCode_5mkicgnmao6w2_name'))]"
        ],
        "tags": {
            "azd-service-name": "app"
        },
        "properties": {
            "allow": false
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to repeat this for slots or any other configuration change to the service, just follow the same process for `Export template`

Answer (score 1):

Basic Authentication configuration setting of function app is used during deployment hence treated as publishing credentials. There are two deployment types uses this credentials

1. Web Deploy
2. FTP
   hence if you want to change this behavior by disabling "Basic Authnetication" to off.

Here is your **bicep code:**

```
resource snScmBasicAuth 'Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'FunctionAppName/scm'
  properties: {
    allow: false
  }
}

resource snFtpBasicAuth 'Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'FunctionAppName/ftp'
  properties: {
    allow: false
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please answer my question in 'UPDATE' section?

Comment: As per bicep compiler and fundamentals you could append slot name to function app with -. What ch means it should be 'functionappname-slotname/SCM