# Disable basic auth for function app & staging slot

Tags: authentication, azure-functions, staging

I have a function app with staging slot with the following settings:

> Basic Authentication : Off

How do I set this for function app and staging slot via bicep?

Comment: Did you not see my tip in your last question, so that you can grab this information for yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267399/bicep-to-set-function-app-general-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I agree to the comment and this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267399/bicep-to-set-function-app-general-settings) answer by **@GordonBy**

> I followed this [**MS Document1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/basicpublishingcredentialspolicies-ftp?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) bicep code for setting Policies-Ftp to false and this [**MS Document2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/basicpublishingcredentialspolicies-scm?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) bicep code for setting Policy-scm to false.

***My Bicep Code referred from this [Blog](https://markheath.net/post/azure-functions-bicep) to Deploy Function app with Basic Authentication set to off:-***

```json
param appName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location

// storage accounts must be between 3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only
var storageAccountName = '${substring(appName,0,10)}${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}' 
var hostingPlanName = '${appName}${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
var appInsightsName = '${appName}${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
var functionAppName = appName

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
    
  }
}

resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02-preview' = {
  name: appInsightsName
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: { 
    Application_Type: 'web'
    publicNetworkAccessForIngestion: 'Enabled'
    publicNetworkAccessForQuery: 'Enabled'
  }
  tags: {
    // circular dependency means we can't reference functionApp directly  /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<appName>"
     'hidden-link:/subscriptions/${subscription().id}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroup().name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/${functionAppName}': 'Resource'
  }
}

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-10-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1' 
    tier: 'Dynamic'
  }
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true

    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, storageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~3'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'dotnet'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, storageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
        }
        // WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE will also be auto-generated - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentshare
        // WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE will be set to 1 by func azure functionapp publish
      ]
    
    }
  }
}

resource functionapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'authsettings'
  kind: 'string'
  parent: functionApp
  properties: {
    enabled: false
  }
}

resource ftpAuth 'Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'ftp'
  kind: 'string'
  parent: functionApp
  properties: {
    allow: false
  }
}

resource scmAuth 'Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'scm'
  kind: 'string'
  parent: functionApp
  properties: {
    allow: false
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***Function app Deployed, and Basic Authentication is set to off.***

[image]